# Is it a bad practice to create a Ruby symbol with accent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, enums

Is there any drawback in creating a `ruby` `symbol` with an accent like this:

```
enum tipo: [:fogo, :água]
```

The word `água` have an accent. When this enum is translated in the form, making it a `string`, by using `.humanize` i get `Água` instead of `Agua` (Which is wrong in Portuguese).

Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: which ruby/rails version are you using? when I use humanize, titleize, or capitalize, I get "água" not "Água" or "Agua".

Comment: @MikeCampbell Actually, the enum, when called like `Class.tipos` returns a hash of `Strings` and `Integers` (`{"fogo => 0, "água" => 1}`). It transformed the symbols into strings, so that's why the `.humanize` method works. I just checked it.

Comment: yes, humanize is a string method provided by ActiveSupport, but it does not result in "Água"—at least not for me.

Comment: @MikeCampbell I reformulate the question to show that `.humanize` is used on the string, instead of the symbol. I just need to know now if there is a problem in using accents in symbols.

Comment: you're kind of ignoring my point that `humanize` does not capitalise the accented "á", but never mind.

no, there is no problem with using accents in symbols.

Comment: There's no problem using accents in symbols. I would not be surprised if the Rails humanize/titleize/etc-type methods sometimes do the wrong thing with non-English though. Doing the right thing such that it works in any arbitrary language turns out to be surprisingly hard, and the Rails features were originally written without thinking much about internationalization.  There are ways to configure your own proper langauge-specific conversions for some of those Rails methods, as well as alternatives to the Rails methods. if that's your question, ask it in a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are internal strings. So in an ideal world there should never be a translation from an external string (given by the user) to a symbol. So there is no real usage for accents in symbols. It's probably a similar question like "should I give my method english names or Portuguese names". However, if you use accents, you should take care that all your source files use the same (hopefully utf-8) encoding. Otherwise you will get problems accessing symbols from sourcefiles with different encodings.
So my suggestion is: use only ASCII chars for symbols as you usually do for method names.

Rails behaviour of "breaking this rule" and translating symbols to strings in forms is just part of rails convention over configuration. I would just write the forms myself (or use rails localization methods) instead of using accents in the symbols.